# How can I initialize TestContext property in another class?

Tags: c#, selenium, mstest

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to perform a data-driven test through CSV file. For this I am defining DataSource attribute in a class which contains test attributes. I am using MStest framework.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1:BaseDriver
{

    ExcelTest sd;

    private TestContext instance;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        set { instance = value; }
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public UnitTest1()
    {

        sd = new ExcelTest(_driver);              
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Testinitialize()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem("TestData.csv")]
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", @"C:\Users\nidumukv\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BMICalculator\BMICalculator\DataFiles\TestData.csv", "TestData#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void DDtest_usingCSV()
    {
        string feet = TestContext.DataRow["feet"].ToString();
        string inches = TestContext.DataRow["inches"].ToString();
        string weight = TestContext.DataRow["weight in pounds"].ToString();
        string BMI = TestContext.DataRow["BMI"].ToString();


        sd.TestUsingCSV(feet,inches,weight,BMI);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void cleanup()
    { _driver.Quit(); }


}
```

BaseDriver is a class I am using to store the actual webdriver. PageElements is a class in which I have declared all the web elements.

I am trying to define the variables that are in 'DDtest_usingCSV' method in a seperate class so that the test does not become clumsy. But whenever I am defining another testcontext in another class I am getting a NullReferenceException. I have tried passing the property between classes. But I could not do it (I am still learning).

Below is the class I am trying to initialize the TestContext

```
 public class ExcelTest:PageElements
{
    public IWebDriver _driver;

    public ExcelTest(IWebDriver driver):base(driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;

    }


    public void TestUsingCSV(string _feet,string _inches,string _weight,string _BMI)
    {
        feet.SendKeys(_feet);
        inches.SendKeys(_inches);
        weight.SendKeys(_weight);
        compute_btn.Click();
    }
}
```

As I could not initialize the property, I am parameterizing that method in the test class file.

And while declaring the TestContext property as mentioned below, why are we using "TestContext" as property name instead of instance??

```
private TestContext instance;
public TestContext TestContext
    {
        set { instance = value; }
        get { return instance; }
    }
```

At the time of reading values from excel, we are taking "TestContext" for accessing DataRow instead of "instance" . This question is bugging me whenever I look at it.

```
public void DDtest_usingCSV()
    {
        string feet = TestContext.DataRow["feet"].ToString();
        string inches = TestContext.DataRow["inches"].ToString();
        string weight = TestContext.DataRow["weight in pounds"].ToString();
        string BMI = TestContext.DataRow["BMI"].ToString();


        sd.TestUsingCSV(feet,inches,weight,BMI);
    }
```

Please don't mind the length of the question. I gave a detailed explanation on my problem. Any help can be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestContext is set automatically by the MSTEST framework but only in the class attributed with [TestClass] and when it executes a test from this class.

In you case, just pass TestContext as a parameter in the TestUsingCSV method of the ExcelTest class.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sergey L. That solved the problem. But is there a way to make the property STATIC and access the property in the "ExcelTest" class? And why are we using the same property name as "TestContext"?

Comment: MSTEST find the property by its name in the test class ([TestClass]) and if it is found, it is assigned with the context. If it is not present in the class, it is not assigned. It cannot be static - it is how MSTEST works.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sergey L.